# How to access WCF Data service on Android without Restlet framework?

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, restlet

I am currently using restlet fw to access WCF Data Service.
I have copied code from restlet support sites but it is not working and giving me error
" Can't get metadata for http://xx.xx.xx/xxService.svc/$metadata--Communication Error[1001]...!

I will appreciate any help with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the remote service is up and running? Can you ping it manually from a web browser for example?

Comment: did you try without a screwdriver or without a hammer ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did that worked for me. In the WCF Service interface:

```
    [OperationContract,WebGet]    
    string Operation1();
```

WCF Service implementation class

```
    string Operation1()
    {
     return "Some text";    
    }
```

In the Java Android client

```
    URL url = new URL("http://xx.xx.xx/xxService.svc/Operation1");
    HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) 
    throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage();
    }
```